# Как правильно посчитать координаты (event.getX() / event.getY()) Объекта с OnTouchListener"ом

Tags: android, bitmap, координаты, ontouchlistener

Всем привет,имеется следующая картина:
[image: source case]

и что мне нужно,так это показывать "часть"(порцию) **битмапа**, посредством координат(Х,У) объекта,который имеет OnTouchListener'a (**оранжевый квадрат**,в центре которого есть точка).

Проблема заключается в том,что мне необходимо отрисовывать изображение так,как это представлено на картинке(красный квадрат - "**Area that i want**", именно в таком формате,я хочу рисовать изображение).
Т.е. в этом случае(см. первую картинку),ожидаемый результат (часть битмапа) :
[image: excepted result]

На текущий момент,я делал вот **это**:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap,view.getX() - view.getWidth(),view.getY()-view.getHeight(),250,250);
            //далее устанавливаю полученный битмап в ImageView
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

И это не совсем правильно работает.
Тем более, при создании битмапа,а именно метод "createBitmap",имеет кое какие ограничения,а именно:

1. начальная координата Х + Width должна быть больше или равна битмапу, который установлен в ImageView(аналогично для У).
2. X/Y должны быть больше нуля.
3. и тд.

В связи с этим,нужно отрисовывать куски битмапа через **Canvas**(посредством прямоугольников).
Я пробовал что то подобное:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(sourcebitmap);
//берем нашу область,посредством текущих координат
Rect RectSource = new Rect(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), 250,250);
//наша область,в которую мы отрисуем результат
RectF RectDest = new RectF(0, 0, 250,250);

canvas.drawBitmap(sourcebitmap,RectSource,RectDest,null);

imageView.SetImageBitmap(sourcebitmap);
```

В данном случае,возникает другой вопрос,а именно то,что метод "drawBitmap",отрисовывает результат поверх "исходника"(т.е. наш RectDest,будет отрисован поверх всего изображения. Как убрать это изображение и оставить только новую "**порцию**" )?

Пробовал различные формулы(перемножение ратио и тд),но так и не получилось. Благодарю заранее!

Comment: Как минимум ваша проблема в том, что координаты вы получаете от точки нажатия на экране, а Bitmap.createBitmap на вход принимает координаты от начала исходного Bitmap, то, что вы туда суёте совсем неправильно. Это как использовать GPS координаты в декардовой системе. Для вашего случая необходимо промежуточное преобразование данных

Comment: @BORSHEVIK я получаю точки вьюшки(координаты Х,У). Да,я понял про что речь,нужен ратио коэффициент,который правильно перемножит координаты? Или можете предложить ваш вариант?

Comment: Что-то вроде. Коэффициент, который правильно приводит одни данные к другим, но скорее некая формула преобразования одних координат в другие

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Решение**:
Имея объект(в моем случае это **оранжевый квадрат**) с прикрученным OnTouchListener"ом(к примеру,наш квадратичный объект имеет размерамы 50dp **Height**/ 50dp **Width**).
То получается, что  **view.getX()/view.getY()** при нажатии,берет относительные **координаты**(центральные) нажатого объекта(к которому прикручен OnTouchListener).
То получается,остается написать вот **это**:

```
//параметры imageview,в котором я буду показывать результат(кусочек области битмапа)
int Width = img.getWidth();
int Height = img.getHeight();
//Теперь, при создании битмапа,я делаю отступ координат по этой формуле: Текущий Х - Width / 2 (аналогично для Y)
 Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap,view.getX() - Width / 2,view.getY()-Height / 2,Width,Height);
```

На это все :).